# I can't create a 3d plot in a presentation using pptx

Tags: python, plot, powerpoint, python-pptx, presentation

I need to insert a 3d plot into the presentation. I decided to try to run the code from the documentation by changing only the plot type, but in the end I got an error. Can you tell me how this can be fixed?

I ran this code.

```
ppt = Presentation() 
slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(ppt.slide_layouts[6])
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.THREE_D_COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)
```

And got the following error

```
NotImplementedError: XML writer for chart type THREE_D_COLUMN_CLUSTERED (54) not yet implemented
```

Comment: Seems like there is no [class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) yet for that chart ( <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>NotImplementedError)